# Is there a good HttpClient library for J2ME/MIDP?

Tags: rest, java-me, midp, cldc

I want to call some RESTful web services from a J2ME client running on a MIDP enabled mobile device. I read the MIDP api for HTTPConnections and thought this is just crying out for a simple wrapper to hide all those unpleasant byte arrays and such like. Before I write my own I wondered whether there was a good open source library already available.

-FE-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check out this little gem, Mobile Ajax for Java ME:

https://meapplicationdevelopers.java.net/mobileajax.html

One part is (from the site):

> Asynchronous I/O for Java ME
>
> This library provides the equivalent
>   of XmlHttpRequest for Java ME with
>   some additional functionality useful
>   for invoking RESTful web services.
>
> It is layered on top of the
>   com.sun.me.web.path library. Features
>   include -
>
> ```
> * Asynchronous versions of HTTP Get and Post
> * HTTP Basic Authentication
> * Multipart MIME (sender only)
> * Progress listeners
> ```

Comment: The link needs fixing as it has an extra http at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

LWUIT 1.5 now includes classes for accessing REST, using OAuth2, JSON, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such library, but found some [succinct example](http://mobile-j2me.blogspot.com/)s of accessing various RESTful web services

Answer (score 0):

We ended up writing our own simple wrapper api for a variety of reasons not the least of which was the fact that the Sony Ericsson K750 that we were developing for had a weird bug (that SE refused to fix) where if you tried to get/use a connection when the device was off network, more than about 20 times, the internal connection pool would get hosed and never recover unless you restarted the app.